# Likelihood of combination of events given multiple independent probabilities?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have seven machines that all operate independently, and each runs for a certain percentage of the day (12%, 17%, 30%, etc.) For simplicity we can label the machines A through G, and we'll just use 'A' = probability of machine A running at any time. So for this question, the probability of machines A and B running at the same time = AB.

If I only had three machines, the probability of at least one machine running is just A+B+C-(AB)-(AC)-(BC)+(ABC). The probability of at least two machines running would be (AB)+(AC)+(BC)-2(ABC). And the probability of all three machines running is just ABC..

But things get hairy when there are four or more machines/variables..

Can someone explain how to solve this problem for seven machines, and find the likelihood that at least one, two, three or four machines are running at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done quickly by multiplying probability generating functions. Think of the two possible states of each  machine as modeled by a flip of an unfair coin that yields either 0 or 1 success.  With three machines, you have three coins, all different, hence three random variables.

The polynomial generating function for the first random variable is $(.88 +.12x^1)$. The probability generating function the sum of all three independent random variables is a product:

$S(x)=(.88 + .12 x)( .83 + .17 x) (.7 + .3 x)$

$= s_0 +s_1 x+ s_2x^2+ s_3 x^3$

$=0.51128 + 0.39356 x + 0.08904 x^2 + 0.00612 x^3$

Thus for example, the probability of exactly $S=2$ successes is the coefficient $s_2= .08904$.

Another useful trick is that the series expansion of $C(x)=S(x)/(1-x) = c_0 + c_1 x+ c_2 x^2+ \ldots$ encodes the cumulative probability distribution, so the coefficient $c_2= s_0+s_1+s_2$ is the probability of at most 2 successes.

All of this generalizes when you have more machines.